# array modifier collapsing on it self

Tags: modeling

[image]

hi, I'm trying to wrap my tank tracks around the wheel with array and curve modifiers but as you can see in the picture it stretches it too thin and it collapses on it self. I have tried fit curve option but it doesn't work pls help me

Comment: maybe apply the scale of your curve (and don't forget to set the vertices radius to 1)?

Comment: can you tell me how to set my vertices to 1?

Comment: Select the curve, go into Edit mode, select all, right click > Set Curve Radius, type 1 and Enter

Comment: thank you so much.

Comment: so was it your problem?

Comment: yes now I'm good

Answer (score 0):

Apply the scale of your curve and set the vertices radius to 1 (go into *Edit* mode, select all, right click > *Set Curve Radius*, type 1 and <kbd>Enter</kbd>).